# ERROR RUNNING B1 EXAMPLE IN WINDOWS 8.1

Tags: windows, session

I am trying to run the B1 example of Geant4 but I've got some issues. I am new in that please helpe me with that..
THE Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 shows me:
**Available UI session types : [ Win32, GAG, csh]

------www-------G4Exception-START------WWW------**

 ExceptionHandler is not defined 

 G4Exception : UI0002
       issued by : G4UIExecutive::G4UIExecutive<>
Specified session type is not build in your system,
or no session type is specified.
A fallback session type is used.
 **This is just a warning message.** 
------www-------G4Exception-END------WWW------
------EEE-------G4Exception-START------EEE------
 **G4Exception : PART70001

        issued by : G4NuclideTable

ENSDFSTATE.dat is not found.**

 Fatal Exception  **core dump ***
------EEE-------G4Exception-END------EEE------
*** G4Exception: Aborting execution *****
Thank you in advance
[image: THE SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you got a -1 for posting your question...i'm sure someone will eventually tell you.

the solution to your problem isn't too difficult, however.

You need to make sure the ENSDFSTATE.dat file is in your system PATH.

This is explained in the geant4 installation instructions.

If you downloaded the data files separately to the geant4 build (meaning: you didn't download the data files as part of your cmake build), then you need to make sure the PATH has the correct 'pointer' to these files.